# How to print values instead of memory addresses for my hashtable? Python

Tags: python, hashtable, memory-address

I'm reading in package data from a csv to my hashtable and when I go to print the data to check if it's being inserted correctly, I'm getting the memory address of the values.  It reads in the packageID and prints that piece correctly.
I apologize for formatting the entire project in one file currently.  I'm new to Python and how the files work together.  When I have them split to separate files in Pycharm I couldn't tell what was being executed since it's dropdown menu would run a single file at a time (my guess)?

```
import csv
import math


####################################################################################################################

class hashtable:
    # Set initial capacity of the Hashtable to 40 and sets the buckets to empty.
    def __init__(self, initial_capacity=40):
        # initialize the hash table with empty bucket list entries.
        self.table = []
        for i in range(initial_capacity):
            self.table.append([])

    # Inserts new key:value pair into desired bucket.
    def insert(self, key, item):  # does both insert and update
        # get the bucket list where this item will go.
        bucket = hash(key) % len(self.table)
        bucket_list = self.table[bucket]
        key_value = [key, item]
        bucket_list.append(key_value)
        return True

    # Searches for the package using its packageID as the key and returns it if found.
    def search(self, key):
        # get the bucket list where this key would be.
        bucket = hash(key) % len(self.table)
        bucket_list = self.table[bucket]
        # print(bucket_list)

        # search for the key in the bucket list
        for kv in bucket_list:
            # print (key_value)
            if kv[0] == key:
                return kv[1]  # value
        return None

    # Removes a package with the matching key.
    def remove(self, key):
        # get the bucket list where this item will be removed from.
        bucket = hash(key) % len(self.table)
        bucket_list = self.table[bucket]

        # remove the item from the bucket list if it is present.
        for kv in bucket_list:
            # print (key_value)
            if kv[0] == key:
                bucket_list.remove([kv[0], kv[1]])


####################################################################################################################

class Package:
    def __init__(self, ID, Address, City, State, Zip, Deadline, Weight, Notes, Status, Deliverytime):
        self.packageID = ID
        self.packageAddress = Address
        self.packageCity = City
        self.packageState = State
        self.packageZip = Zip
        self.packageDeadline = Deadline
        self.packageWeight = Weight
        self.packageNotes = Notes
        self.packageStatus = Status
        self.deliveryTime = Deliverytime


#####################################################################################################################


def loadPackageData(fileName):
    with open(fileName) as Package_List:
        packageData = csv.reader(Package_List, delimiter=',')
        for package in packageData:
            pID = int(package[0])
            pAddress = package[1]
            pCity = package[2]
            pState = package[3]
            pZip = package[4]
            pDeadline = package[5]
            pWeight = package[6]
            pNotes = package[7]
            pStatus = "At hub"
            pDeliverytime = "00:00"

            #package object
            p = Package(pID, pAddress, pCity, pState, pZip, pDeadline, pWeight, pNotes, pStatus, pDeliverytime)
            #print (p)

            # insert into the hash table
            myHash.insert(pID, p)

# Hash table instance
myHash = hashtable()

# Load packages to Hashtable
loadPackageData('packageData.csv')

print("Packages from Hashtable:")
print(myHash.table)
# Fetch data from hashtable
#for i in range (len(myHash.table)+1):
#    print("Package: {}".format(myHash.search(i+1))) # 1 to 40 sent to myHash.search()
```

When print(myHash.table) is called I get output structured like this except for all 40 packages.

```
[[[40, <__main__.Package object at 0x000001E1489114C0>]], [[1, <__main__.Package object at 0x000001E148914220>]], [[2, <__main__.Package object at 0x000001E148911DF0>]], [[3, <__main__.Package object at 0x000001E148911D00>]]
```

I couldn't understand how to implement another post asking a similar question with my project so I am here now.  I really appreciate all of you for any help!

Comment: Write a `__repr__()` method for your `Package` class that prints what you want.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the hash table. You would have the same problem if you were just printing a variable containing a `Package` object.

Comment: Why are you implementing your own hash table instead of just using a dictionary?

Comment: Why does it matter how it prints out? That's just how your o texts are being represented when printing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must override [`__repr__` and `__str__`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/str-vs-repr-in-python/) methods for class to be able print what you need.

In other way you may add own `human_readable`-like property

```py
class PackageA:
  def __init__(self, ID, Address, City, State, Zip, Deadline, Weight, Notes, Status, Deliverytime):
    self.packageID = ID
    self.packageAddress = Address
    self.packageCity = City
    self.packageState = State
    self.packageZip = Zip
    self.packageDeadline = Deadline
    self.packageWeight = Weight
    self.packageNotes = Notes
    self.packageStatus = Status
    self.deliveryTime = Deliverytime

class PackageB:
  def __init__(self, ID, Address, City, State, Zip, Deadline, Weight, Notes, Status, Deliverytime):
    self.packageID = ID
    self.packageAddress = Address
    self.packageCity = City
    self.packageState = State
    self.packageZip = Zip     
    self.packageDeadline = Deadline
    self.packageWeight = Weight
    self.packageNotes = Notes
    self.packageStatus = Status
    self.deliveryTime = Deliverytime

  def __str__(self):
    return f'STR is <{self.packageID} {self.packageAddress} {self.packageCity} {self.packageState} {self.packageZip} {self.packageDeadline} {self.packageWeight} {self.packageNotes} {self.packageStatus} {self.deliveryTime}>'

  def __repr__(self):
    return f'REPR is <{self.packageID} {self.packageAddress} {self.packageCity} {self.packageState} {self.packageZip} {self.packageDeadline} {self.packageWeight} {self.packageNotes} {self.packageStatus} {self.deliveryTime}>'

  @property
  def human_readable(self):
    return f'Readable representation is <{self.packageID} {self.packageAddress} {self.packageCity} {self.packageState} {self.packageZip} {self.packageDeadline} {self.packageWeight} {self.packageNotes} {self.packageStatus} {self.deliveryTime}>'

packagesA = []
packagesB = []

for i in range(0,3):
  packagesA.append(PackageA(f"ID{i}", f"Address{i}", f"City{i}", f"State{i}", f"Zip{i}", f"Deadline{i}", f"Weight{i}", f"Notes{i}", f"Status{i}", f"Deliverytime{i}"))
  packagesB.append(PackageB(f"ID{i}", f"Address{i}", f"City{i}", f"State{i}", f"Zip{i}", f"Deadline{i}", f"Weight{i}", f"Notes{i}", f"Status{i}", f"Deliverytime{i}"))


print(packagesA)
print("--")
print(packagesB)
print("--")
print([str(x) for x in packagesB])
print("--")
print([x.human_readable for x in packagesB])
```

Output:

```
[<__main__.PackageA object at 0x104ca0710>, <__main__.PackageA object at 0x104ca0a90>, <__main__.PackageA object at 0x104ca0e10>]
--
[REPR is <ID0 Address0 City0 State0 Zip0 Deadline0 Weight0 Notes0 Status0 Deliverytime0>, REPR is <ID1 Address1 City1 State1 Zip1 Deadline1 Weight1 Notes1 Status1 Deliverytime1>, REPR is <ID2 Address2 City2 State2 Zip2 Deadline2 Weight2 Notes2 Status2 Deliverytime2>]
--
['STR is <ID0 Address0 City0 State0 Zip0 Deadline0 Weight0 Notes0 Status0 Deliverytime0>', 'STR is <ID1 Address1 City1 State1 Zip1 Deadline1 Weight1 Notes1 Status1 Deliverytime1>', 'STR is <ID2 Address2 City2 State2 Zip2 Deadline2 Weight2 Notes2 Status2 Deliverytime2>']
--
['Readeable representation is <ID0 Address0 City0 State0 Zip0 Deadline0 Weight0 Notes0 Status0 Deliverytime0>', 'Readeable representation is <ID1 Address1 City1 State1 Zip1 Deadline1 Weight1 Notes1 Status1 Deliverytime1>', 'Readeable representation is <ID2 Address2 City2 State2 Zip2 Deadline2 Weight2 Notes2 Status2 Deliverytime2>']
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case it is printing the python objects default `__repr__()` which prints `classname<memory location>`. You would want to write a custom `__repr__()` that returns a string of what data you want to show up there.

So in your case you might want to do something like this:

```py
class Package:
    def __init__(self, ID, Address, City, State, Zip, Deadline, Weight, Notes, Status, Deliverytime):
        self.packageID = ID
        self.packageAddress = Address
        self.packageCity = City
        self.packageState = State
        self.packageZip = Zip
        self.packageDeadline = Deadline
        self.packageWeight = Weight
        self.packageNotes = Notes
        self.packageStatus = Status
        self.deliveryTime = Deliverytime
    
    def __repr__(self):
        # Creates a list of lists where [value, attribute]
        attributes = [[getattr(self, attr), attr] for attr in dir(self) if not attr.startswith("__")]

        # Start result string with classname
        result = "Package("

        for attribute in attributes:
            result += f"{attribute[1]}= {attribute[0]},"
        
        result+=")"
        return result

print(Package(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)) # prints Package(deliveryTime= 1,packageAddress= 1,packageCity= 1,packageDeadline= 1,packageID= 1,packageNotes= 1,packageState= 1,packageStatus= 1,packageWeight= 1,packageZip= 1,)
```

This is a very quick and dirty implementation you can clean up to be faster and do what you want exactly, but basically it steps through the class and goes through each non dunder (starting with `__`) attribute, and then creates a string that is in the form of `classname(attribute=value,)` for every attribute in the class.

Looking at your class you could also use the [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) module because you have so many attributes, but since I don't know the types I can't give you a solution, or use a [namedtuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple). All of these have built in `__repr__()` functions.